Artisan migrate with ci/cd on azure container app
I am mouting a container app that is working fine.
Before for migration I was passing by ssh directly in my container app. But now I want to after push and deploy my docker image, it will launch my migration and seeder.
In web app it was not complicated but I can't find a way to do that in container app
name: Trigger auto deployment for web

# When this action will be executed
on:
 # Automatically trigger it when detected changes in repo
 push:
   branches:
     [ test-arnaud ]
   paths:
   - '**'
   - '.github/workflows/web-AutoDeployTrigger-1ae8bc9c-b556-46e6-bf83-02fb4f7e5ef1.yml'

 # Allow manual trigger
 workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
 build-and-deploy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   permissions:
     id-token: write #This is required for requesting the OIDC JWT Token
     contents: read #Required when GH token is used to authenticate with private repo

   steps:
     - name: Checkout to the branch
       uses: actions/checkout@v2

     - name: Azure Login
       uses: azure/login@v1
       with:
         client-id: ${{ secrets.KINGWEB_AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
         tenant-id: ${{ secrets.KINGWEB_AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
         subscription-id: ${{ secrets.KINGWEB_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

     - name: Build and push container image to registry
       uses: azure/container-apps-deploy-action@v2
       with:
         appSourcePath: ${{ github.workspace }}
         _dockerfilePathKey_: _dockerfilePath_
         registryUrl: container.azurecr.io
         registryUsername: ${{ secrets.KINGWEB_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
         registryPassword: ${{ secrets.KINGWEB_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
         containerAppName: web
         resourceGroup: king-plateforme-neu-dev-rg
         imageToBuild: container.azurecr.io/web:${{ github.sha }}
         _buildArgumentsKey_: |
           _buildArgumentsValues_



I try with some az containerapp exec with no success.
I know for GCP it was little tricky but succeed by finding some obscur things :) but for azure container apps I am out of mind.
thanks a lot
UPDATE
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:8.3-alpine

# Installation dans votre Image du minimum pour que Docker fonctionne
RUN apk add oniguruma-dev libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        ctype \
        fileinfo \
        mbstring \
        pdo_mysql \
        xml

# Installation dans votre image de Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Installation dans votre image de NodeJS
RUN apk add nodejs npm

ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT /app/public
ENV APP_ENV production
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# On copie le fichier .env.example pour le renommer en .env
# Vous pouvez modifier le .env.example pour indiquer la configuration de votre site pour la production
RUN cp -n .env.example .env

# Installation et configuration de votre site pour la production
# https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#optimizing-configuration-loading
RUN composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
# Generate security key
RUN php artisan key:generate
# Optimizing Configuration loading
RUN php artisan config:cache
# Optimizing Route loading
RUN php artisan route:cache
# Optimizing View loading
RUN php artisan view:cache

# Compilation des assets de Breeze (ou de votre site)
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

RUN chown -R application:application .
CMD ["sh", "-c", "run_migration_and_seed.sh"]

Adding that to my dockerfil seems not launching the .sh
I added just a php artisan migrate into my sh
#24 [stage-0 16/16] RUN chown -R application:application .
#24 DONE 4.8s

#25 exporting to image
#25 exporting layers
#25 exporting layers 8.1s done
#25 writing image sha256:ae2742756b94b1973d1f6dd0b9178e233c73a2a86f0ba7657b59e7e5a75f5b2d done

UPDATE FINAL
I do a function APP in node JS to call the php artisan migrate and in my yaml I call this function for my container, it's working well too. thanks all

Modify Dockerfile to Check the migration and seeding commands run as part of the container's startup. CMD ["sh", "-c", "run_migration_and_seed.sh && start_server.sh"]

Alternate approach - Azure Jobs is a great feature for running one-off tasks, like migrations or seeders in the container.

I search the doc for that if it's better to use this one

please modify your question rather than posting it as an answer.

done sorry for that

You can use the same image for azure jobs but specify a different command and args in the job configuration.

Above issue lies in the way you are defining and attempting to run the shell script (run_migration_and_seed.sh).
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:8.3-alpine

# Install required dependencies
RUN apk add oniguruma-dev libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    ctype \
    fileinfo \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    xml

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Install Node.js and npm
RUN apk add nodejs npm

# Set environment variables
ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT /app/public
ENV APP_ENV production

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy application files
COPY . .

# Ensure `.env` exists
RUN cp -n .env.example .env

# Install dependencies and optimize the application
RUN composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN php artisan key:generate
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan view:cache

# Build frontend assets
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R application:application .

# Copy and set permissions for the migration script
COPY run_migration_and_seed.sh /usr/local/bin/run_migration_and_seed.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run_migration_and_seed.sh

# Set the command to run migrations and start the server
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/run_migration_and_seed.sh"]

The CMD syntax is incorrect. check it uses the absolute path to the script.
With Azure Container Apps Jobs, you can run specific workloads on-demand or on a schedule using the same container image as the  main application, but configured to perform different tasks.
You can reuse your existing container image or create a specific one for migrations and seeding.
Dockerfile:
FROM your-base-image

# Add migration script
COPY run_migration_and_seed.sh /usr/local/bin/run_migration_and_seed.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run_migration_and_seed.sh

# Default to running the application
CMD ["sh", "-c", "if [ \"$IS_MIGRATION\" = \"true\" ]; then run_migration_and_seed.sh; else start_server.sh; fi"]

After deploying your container, you can trigger the job to run migrations in your GitHub Actions workflow.
- name: Trigger migration job
  run: |
    az containerapp job run \
      --name migration-job \
      --resource-group king-plateforme-neu-dev-rg \
      --env-vars DATABASE_URL="your-db-connection-string"

